# How do I pass a object and access data through a function

Tags: php, oop

I created  a item class (item.class.php) and itemDAO class (itemDAO.class.php) and I have another php file (test.php). I want to inset a data to database using those classes from test.php class. Also I have a database class (db.class.php). Here I'm stuck with by getting the object's (item) values to the function in itemDAO class.

Here is my item.class.php

```
<?php

class item {

    private $id;
    private $name;
    private $description;


    public function item($_id,$_name,$_description){

        $this->id=$_id;
        $this->name=$_name;
        $this->description=$_description;

    }

    public function setId( $id )
    {
        $this->id = $id;
    }

    public function setName( $name )
    {
        $this->name = $name;
    }

    public function setDescription( $description )
    {
        $this->description = $description;
    }

    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function getDescription()
    {
        return $this->description;
    }       
}
?>
```

This is my itemDAO.class.php

```
<?php
include("db.class.php");
include("item.class.php");

class itemDAO {

    public function __construct() {
        $d=new db();
    }

    public function AddItem(&$item) { //I am stuck here 

        $result = $db->query("INSERT INTO item VALUES('$i->') ");//Im stuck here 
    }
}
?>
```

How can I get the item class object to get values from the object and pass to the sql query.
I'm poor in php and know java well.
In java we can just call like this

```
public boolean addItem(Item I) {

    String query = "insert into Item(Item_Id, Item_Name, Item_Category, Measuring_Unit, Last_Price_Rate)  values ('" + I.getItemID() + "','" + I.getItemName() + "','" + I.getItemCategory() + "','" + I.getMeasuringUnit() + "','" + I.getLastPriceRate() + "')";
    System.out.println(query);
}
```

this is my test.php

```
<?php
include("item.class.php");
include("db.class.php");
include("itemDAO.class.php");
$id="3";
$name="aaa";
$descriptio="hi";
$item= new item($id,$name,$descriptio);

$dao=new itemDAO();
$dao->AddItem($item->getId(),$item->getName(),$item->getDescription());
?>
```

my database class

```
<?php

class db {

    private $link;
   // private $host="localhost", $username="root", $password="123", $database="item";

    public function __construct(){
        $this->host        = "localhost";
        $this->username    = "root";
        $this->password    = "123";
        $this->database    = "item";

        $this->link = mysql_connect($this->host, $this->username, $this->password)
            OR die("There was a problem connecting to the database.");

        mysql_select_db($this->database, $this->link)
            OR die("There was a problem selecting the database.");

        return true;
    }

    public function query($query) {
        $result = mysql_query($query);
        if (!$result) die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
        return $result;
    }

    public function __destruct() {
        mysql_close($this->link)
            OR die("There was a problem disconnecting from the database.");
    }
}
?>
```

How can I do this same thing with PHP with Object Orientation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pleas stop passing around objects by reference. It is not necessary since PHP5.x, instead object by default are passed around using handlers.

```
class itemDAO{

    protected $db;

    public function __construct( $db ){
        $this->db= $db;
    }

    public function AddItem( $item ){ 

        $query = 'INSERT INTO Item(Item_Id, Item_Name, Item_Category)  
                  VALUE ( :id, :name, :category )';
        $statement = $this->db->prepare( $query );
        $statement->bindParam( ':id', $item->getId(), PDO::PARAM_INT );
        $statement->bindParam( ':name', $item->getName() );
        $statement->bindParam( ':category', $item->getCategory() );

        return $statement->execute(); // returns false if query fails.
    }

}
```

If you know the basics of PHP have previous experience with Java, then I would recommend you to read [*"PHP in Action"*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1932394753). That will cover OOP in PHP in Java-friendly manner.

Also I suspect, that you might benefit from reading [this article](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers). It would explain you how to use PDO API ( assuming that this is what you were using already).

And you need to learn how to utilize `spl_autoload_register()`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.Can I knw what is prepare function and bind param function? according to your code can you show me yout database class?

Comment: Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions to write new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ). See the [*red box*](http://goo.gl/GPmFd)? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide which, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help you. If you pick PDO, [here is good tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Comment: @S_LCB , that one above is a standard comment for `mysql_*` users. Read the links. It will explain "why", "what" and "how".

Answer (score 0):

It's not really that different, just remember that to concatenate in PHP use a period, and to access object properties use "->" instead of a period.

```
public function AddItem(&$item)
    $result = $db->query("insert into Item(Item_Id, Item_Name, Item_Category, Measuring_Unit, Last_Price_Rate)  values ('" . $item->getItemID() . "','" . $item->getItemName() . "','" . $item->getItemCategory() . "','" . $item->getMeasuringUnit() . "','" . $item->getLastPriceRate() . "')");
}
```

Also, on another note, remember that in PHP constructors are not just the objects name. You have to make a function called `__construct`.

Comment: &$item doesnt work even  $item-> doenst show sugessions in dreamveaver

Comment: Show us the actual test file that you pass $item with.

Comment: I added test.php file to this post

Comment: I added my databse class also